# grep count all matches in one line of single pattern

Tags: grep

How can I count *all* matches with grep, when there are *more* than one match per line?

```
$ cat example.txt
int foo(int a, char b) { int i = 80; return i; }
$ grep -c "int" example.txt
1
```

I want to output `3` (since `int` appears 3 times in the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep` that supports `-o` option:

```sh
$ grep -o 'int' ip.txt | wc -l
3
```

With [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```sh
$ rg -oc 'int' ip.txt
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this `awk` approach using search word a field separator:

```sh
awk -F 'int' '{print NF-1}' file

3
```

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use awk for this:

```
$ awk '{c+=gsub(/int/,"")}END{print c}' file
```

The function `gsub` is used to perform substitutions and returns the total amount of substitutions done. In the above, we replace the regular expression `int` with an empty string to do the counting. This is done for every line of `file`. Per line, we add the count to the variable `c` which is by default initialized to zero. At the `END` of the script, we print the value of `c`.

Comment: can you please provide a short explanation what each part does?